# How Can I see the Implementation of my Api Interface generated by Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, square

I was curious to see the Implementation of my Api Interface generated by the Retrofit to see how actually the library handles network requests. I wasn't able to find any generated class related to the Retrofit library inside the build folder where the generated classes by different libraries are generally located.

Hence, I wanted to ask
What is the reason for hiding the Implementation?
How can I see the Api Interface Implementation generated by Retrofit?

Though it's not needed but my Api Interface looks like this

```
interface LaunchesApi {

    @GET("launch/upcoming")
    suspend fun getLaunches(
        @Query("offset")
        offset: Int = 0
    ): LaunchesResponseDto

}
```

I tried searching throughout the project for the Implementation but I couldn't find it

Comment: AFAIK RetroFit does not generate code at compile time . It uses Proxy to generate code at runtime So you can not see it .. that's the story i know i maybe wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit doesn't generate code at compile time. It uses runtime reflection to proxy service interface calls to execute its internal behavior. Your best bet is to investigate Retrofit's sources directly.

### Links

1. [`Retrofit.create`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/fcfaac3fa98980f6132d6c3ece2a684121b73127/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java#L146)
2. [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)